# union type with number | never is this acceptable?

Tags: typescript

We get examples of never being a function that always throws an error or one that contains and infinite loop.

Never is never, it never happens.

But throwing an error is not `void` nor `undefined`, throwing an error is `never`

So is it not possible to use never in a union? It sounds illogical, yet it's logical. **At the end of the day, it is providing accurate context, is it not?**

```
foo(input: string): number | never {
    if (input === 'bazz') {
        return 5;
    }
    throw new Error('could not do it');
}
```

Comment: never is not an appropriate return value for function foo. This function returns and only returns a number. that is your only return type. in cases that input is not bazz the program stops as an exception is thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8652) introducing `never` clearly states that `T | never` is always `T`:

> Because never is a subtype of every type, it is always omitted from union types and it is ignored in function return type inference as long as there are other types being returned.

`never` is the appropriate return type only when a function never returns. There is no way to model the equivalent of Java `throws` in typescript.